# Checkbox and POST

Tags: python, django

My current view does a delete and create functions.

You can delete an item using a checkbox.

Is there anyway to do a editable table?
I mean maybe change a way of showing my database at a template, and adding a save button?

Here's a screenshot

http://postimg.org/image/uromygv7f/

Here's views.py

```
def task1(request):

    if request.POST and 'create' in request.POST:
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        args['authors'] = Author.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('tasks/task1.html',args)
    elif request.POST and 'delete' in request.POST:

        """form= AuthorForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        args['authors'] = Author.objects.all()"""

        Author.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('item')).delete()
        return render_to_response('tasks/task1.html')
    else:
        form = AuthorForm()




    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    args['authors'] = Author.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('tasks/task1.html',args)
```

and a template

```
<form action="/task1/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_table}}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Create"  name="create"/>

    {% if authors.count > 0 %}
    {% for author in authors %}
    <ul>
        {{author.id}}  {{author.name}} {{author.body}} {{author.deletes }}     <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{author.pk}}">
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"  name="delete"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. ID numbers in the database don't change if you delete other items: why should they? And if you have two questions, you should ask them separately.

Comment: Please don't chameleon your question. The edited post is different than the original rendering my question irrelevant too.

Comment: Sorry for that, thought the edits a shown for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Django documentation: Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/):

> An id field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden. See [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

This is an auto-increment field which allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table. This number does not automatically change after update or delete. For more information see for example the [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) (implementations vary across different db's but you can get an idea).

Due to the fact that the id field does not automatically change, sorting shouldn't be affected. You can still sort the table on id. If you wish to have an auto-increment (1, 2, 3, ...) field displayed in your template, you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.